# Displacement of water - Archimedes' principle

Tags: water, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy, displacement

Floating objects displace their weight and objects that are completely submerged in water displace their volume. So, my question is that does a floating object displace less water than an immersed object?

Comment: _Floating objects displace their weight_ No. In general object displace volume of liquid, which equals to the volume of submerged body part in fluid.

Comment: You said that floating objects don't displace their weight but why?

Comment: So does this mean that the buoyant force exerted on floating objects is the same as their weight? -Mechanic

Comment: @moonchild, floating objects displace their weight of whatever fluid they are floating in.

Comment: @moonchild It's about [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy): _Any object, wholly or partially immersed in a fluid, is buoyed up by a force equal to the weight of the fluid displaced by the object_, i.e. buoyancy force is $B=\rho _{f}V_{\text{disp}}\,g,\,$. So the more submerged body is into the liquid,- the bigger  buoyancy force, because body will "push-out" more fluid. It doesn't matter body is partially or fully submerged into the fluid for buoyancy to work. Why it is so ? Ask mother nature.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider two different boxes with the same dimension (assume cube for simplicity), the floating object will displace less water.

This means that a less buoyant force is acting on it. However, it is floating because the buoyant force is larger compared to it's weight.

Comment: Okay.One more question. I read this somewhere that a floating object displaces the amount of water that's equal to its own weight for example ships. Is this correct? If so then is it always the case?