# DISPLACEMENT OF WATER

Tags: water, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy, displacement

Floating objects displace their weight?
what does this statement actually mean?
Does this mean that floating objects displace the amount of water that's equal to their weight and so buoyancy is equal to to gravity?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713840/2451

Comment: [Archimedes principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a body of water where with a cylindrical depression in it. The water on the floor of this depression would experience a net upward force because of pressure from water around it. The hole would quickly fill in.

The force needed to keep the floor still is the weight of enough water to fill the hole. And the upward force from the floor is just the right amount to hold up the water that fills the hole.

You can fill the hole with a block of wood that has the same mass as that block of water. Gravity would push it downward with the same force as the block of water, so it would hold back the floor. The floor would push upward with the same force and hold the block still.

Wood is less dense than water, so the volume of the wood block would be larger. The cylinder would be longer and would stick up above the surface.